# Why algorithm doesn't work?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 2 collections and I want to get elements of second collection, which don't exist in the first one. Because of the big size of both collections, I created a special algorithm to do it (below there is link to example project):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Object-shell of point with coordinates
    /// </summary>
    class Point
    {
        public Point(string coordinates)
        {
            var parts = coordinates.Split(' ');
            Latitude = double.Parse(parts[0]);
            Longitude = double.Parse(parts[1]);
        }

        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }

    class PointComparer : IComparer<Point>
    {
        private const double Eps = 1e-4;

        /// <summary>
        /// Before compare latitude, than longitude
        /// </summary>
        public int Compare(Point first, Point second)
        {
            var latCompare = Compare(first.Latitude, second.Latitude);

            if (latCompare == 0)
                return 0;

            return Compare(first.Longitude, second.Longitude);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare two double numbers with specified occuracy
        /// </summary>
        private int Compare(double first, double second)
        {
            var temp = first - second;

            if (Math.Abs(temp) < Eps)
                return 0;

            if (temp < 0)
                return -1;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find objects of 2 collection, which don't exist in 1 collection
    /// For example f({1,2,3}, {1,2,4}) = {4}
    /// </summary>
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetNewT<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        //Sort both collections
        var sortedFirst = first.OrderBy(i => i, comparer).ToList();
        var sortedSecond = second.OrderBy(i => i, comparer).ToList();

        //Because of 2 collection was sorted after we find item of second collection in 'i' place of first collection,
        //we can to find next item of second collection after 'i' place of first collection.
        int startSearchIndex = 0;

        //Try to find object of seconed collection in first collectio via Binary Search
        foreach (var item in sortedSecond)
        {
            var countToSearch = sortedFirst.Count - startSearchIndex;
            var findResultIndex = sortedFirst.BinarySearch(startSearchIndex, countToSearch, item, comparer);

            if (findResultIndex >= 0) //Find it!
            {
                startSearchIndex = findResultIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

So it doesn't work, but I can't find any mistake in it. [There is a link to example project with example data to see problem.](http://nekaka.com/d/A4Hj4LXE53)

Comment: Is there a reason you ruled out `list2.Except(list1).ToList()`?

Comment: `if (latCompare == 0) return 0;` This is most likely the opposite of what you intended to do.

Comment: What is big in this case? (To big for a `HashSet` is *quite* big on a modern machines)

Comment: Jeroen Vannevel, This mathod have this signature:
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(..., IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer);
As you can see it use IEqualityComparer so I assume that it cross second collection by each element of first collection. So it have n^2 performance. My algotigm have n*log(n) performance. And as I said before I have big collection to check.

Comment: Rotem, you right - there is a mistake in this. Thank you!

Comment: @RustamSalahutdinov anyway: try using HashSets or simply the Except Jeroen mentioned - most likely it will be faster than your implementation (btw: yours has the same signature - so why do you think that the framework version is doing the most naive implementation?)

Comment: @Carsten König. Ok
(I use IComparer<T>, system use IEqualityComparer<T>. IComparer can tell you if 1 object biger or smaller than 2. IEqualityComparer can tell you only equals of it.)

Comment: @RustamSalahutdinov you only need this for sorting - for example hashsets don't more than ... well the hashcode - anyway it's useless to argue - if you don't won't to you don't have to try

Answer (score 1):

Rotem find mistake in this code:
There must be:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Before compare latitude, than longitude
        /// </summary>
        public int Compare(Point first, Point second)
        {
            var latCompare = Compare(first.Latitude, second.Latitude);

            if (latCompare == 0)
                return Compare(first.Longitude, second.Longitude);

            return latCompare;
        }
```